# How do I get many frames at once?

Tags: python, opencv, mpi

I am writing a program in Python that grabs all of the frames in a given input video and does some processing to each frame. I am running this program on a cluster of machines and want to parallelize this program by having each process be responsible for processing a single frame using MPI.

I am using cv2 to read the frames of the input video. cv2 offers a function [grab](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-grab) to obtain frames of the input video one at a time. Is there another function I can use to get a list of frames all at once? I want to perform a scatter operation on these frames to disperse them to individual processes, and then use a gather at the end to combine all the now processed frames. Grabbing each frame one at a time seems to be serializing the whole program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking about two possible scenarios:

1) Grabbing each frames is a considerably a light operation, in contrast with the real processing of each frame.  In this case, "serializing" the grabbing part is not really a problem.

or

2) Each host in the cluster has the responsibility of grabbing a specific set of frames.  So instead of "dispersing frames", you can "disperse frame numbers" and the hosts do the job.

Comment: Thanks, 1 would work... For 2, what can each host do with the frame numbers? Is there random access to a frame in a video?

Comment: For 2: I really don't remember the features of OpenCV, but I'm pretty sure there is a way of retrieving a specific frame from a video.  Plus, you will only have to send a set of integers instead of large matrices to each host.